# Chapter displayed in headings and page number on the left

Tags: header-footer, memoir

I am writing my thesis using the class `memoir`. I have two problems to get nice headings/footers. First, I want the page number to be in the footer, on the right or on the left but for the first page of a chapter, it stays centered. Then, for pages with an even number, I want the name of the current chapter to be inserted in the headings. I can not find how to do these things. Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\nouppercaseheads
\makepagestyle{these}
\makeevenhead{these}{\rightmark}{}{}
\makeoddhead{these}{}{}{\leftmark}
\makeheadrule{these}{\textwidth}{\normalrulethickness}
\makeevenfoot{these}{\thepage}{}{}
\makeoddfoot{these}{}{}{\thepage}
\makepsmarks{these}{%
\createmark{section}{left}{shownumber}{}{\ } 
\createmark{chapter}{right}{shownumber}{}{\ }
\createplainmark{toc}{both}{\contentsname}}
\pagestyle{these}

\makeatother

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\frontmatter

\title{My title} 

\maketitle

\chapter{Thanks}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Introduction}\label{intro}
\Blindtext

\mainmatter
\part{1st Part}

\chapter{My Chapter}
\section{My Section}

\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

Comment: [welcome to tex.stackexchange!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) The example you're providing is not going to work other people's machines, as we don't have `intro.tex.` If you simply want to fill your document with some text for demonstration purposes, please use the `blindtext` package an its commands like `\Blinddocument` etc.

Comment: You really should use `\frontmatter` and `\mainmatter` instead of that whole hackery with `\chapter*` and `\addtocontents`.

Comment: I made the changes both of you asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surely there must be a question on this site, which already give the answer to this, but you could do something like:

```
\documentclass[
a4paper, % Stock and paper size.
11pt, % Type size.
% article,
% oneside, 
onecolumn, % Only one column of text on a page.
% openright, % Each chapter will start on a recto page.
% openleft, % Each chapter will start on a verso page.
openany, % A chapter may start on either a recto or verso page.
]{memoir}

\usepackage{lipsum} % Will come in handy below...

%%% HEADER AND FOOTER 
%%%--------------------------------------------------------------

\makepagestyle{standard} % Make standard pagestyle

\makeatletter                 % Define standard pagestyle
\makeevenfoot{standard}{}{}{\thepage} % Even footer
\makeoddfoot{standard}{\thepage}{}{}  % Odd Footer
\makeevenhead{standard}{}{\leftmark}{} % ...
\makeoddhead{standard}{}{\leftmark}{}  %
% \makeheadrule{standard}{\textwidth}{\normalrulethickness}
\makeatother                  %

\makeatletter % Make marks (to put chapter title etc. in the header)
\makepsmarks{standard}{
\createmark{chapter}{both}{shownumber}{\@chapapp\ }{ \quad }
\createmark{section}{right}{shownumber}{}{ \quad }
\createplainmark{toc}{both}{\contentsname}
\createplainmark{lof}{both}{\listfigurename}
\createplainmark{lot}{both}{\listtablename}
\createplainmark{bib}{both}{\bibname}
\createplainmark{index}{both}{\indexname}
\createplainmark{glossary}{both}{\glossaryname}
}
\makeatother   

\makepagestyle{chap} % Make new chapter pagestyle

\makeatletter
\makeevenfoot{chap}{}{\thepage}{} % Define new chapter pagestyle
\makeoddfoot{chap}{}{\thepage}{}  %
\makeevenhead{chap}{}{}{}   %
\makeoddhead{chap}{}{}{}    %
% \makeheadrule{chap}{\textwidth}{\normalrulethickness}
\makeatother

\nouppercaseheads
\pagestyle{standard}               % Choosing pagestyle and chapter pagestyle
\aliaspagestyle{chapter}{chap} %

%%% DOCUMENT
%%%----------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-10]

\chapter{Conclusions and Outlook}
\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

I'm not sure that this is exactly what you desire. If not, I hope the code is clear enough for you to make the changes yourself.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I can now make the changes I want. For an unknown reason, I thus have to use `\createmark` with `both` and `right` rather than with `left` and `right`. The command `\aliaspagesstyle` allows me to modify the style of the first page of each chapter.